# Run tasks after requesting a shut down

Tags: 12.04, unity, scripts, customization, automation

I have a small internet cafe with 7-9 Ubuntu 12.04 workstations. Unfortunately, I can't be there every week.

I've seen a Java solution to upgrade the system, after a normal (non-sudo/admin) user requests a shut down (but not restart!) the system upgrades itself - the base system is Ubuntu 10.04 as I remember, but the programs, and the desktop manager is fully customized, with custom softwares (eg. to check the printers' ink level...)

That's why I thought, that if I could set up something similar in our environment, it would be very useful. I've already scripted in Bash, and used [Zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity), so I only want to know:

1. how can I call/run my script?
2. how can I run root commands(sudo required) inside that script? (eg. sudo poweroff or halt)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of what you can do.

If you want to check for an upgrade every time the machine is going down you can turn your script into a system v init-script that will run on level 0 (shutdown).

To do this:

1. change your script to be an init script. 
   Quick example - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html
2. put it in /etc/init.d/
3. create a symlink like: /etc/rc0.d/K01myscipt -> /etc/init.d/myscript

This will send a stop command (**K** 01myscript) to your script at the beginning of shutdown process (K **01** myscript - meaning, before others). I'm not sure, but maybe you'll have to cancel shutdown at the beginning of the script - `shutdown -c now` and issue it again at the end - `shutdown -h now`.

The script will be executed already as root so you don't need any sudo commands. You just need to have permissions create the mentioned files.